# Why won't my JavaScript run in HTML Visual Code

Tags: javascript, html

My JavaScript won't run for my landing page clock. I have tried to put the JavaScript in the head and in the body but it still will not make my clock tick. What is wrong with my code? How do I fix this?

```js
const time = document.getElementById('time'),
  greeting = document.getElementById('greeting'),
  name = document.getElementById('name'),
  focus = document.getElementById('focus');

function showTime() {
  let today = new Date(),
    hour = today.getHours(),
    min = today.getMinutes(),
    sec = today.getSeconds();
  //Set Am or PM
  const amPM = hour >= 12 ? 'PM' : 'AM';

  //12hr Format 
  hour = hour % 12 || 12;

  //Output Time
  time.innerHTML = '${hour}<span>:</span>${min}<span>:</span>${sec}';

  setTimeout(showTime, 1000);
}
Run
showTime();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" <head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial- 
     scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2? 
     family=Quicksand&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" <title>Welcome Page</title>
</head>

<body>
  <time id="time">12:34:56 PM</time>
  <h1>
    <span id="greeting">Good Afternoon</span>
    <span id="name" contenteditable="true">Heather</span>
  </h1>

  <h2>What Is Your Focus For Today?</h2>
  <h2 id="focus" contenteditable="true">FIX THIS ISH ! </h2>
  <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Have you looked in your browser's console to see if there are any errors?

Comment: Please share more details. What **exactly** is not working? What have you tried to make it work?

Comment: Your javascript doesn't look valid, what is `Run`? You probably have an error in the dev tools console.

Comment: Your HTML is also not valid, missing the ends of tags (`>`).

Comment: Also your html looks malformed: `<html lang="en" <head>` missing closing `>` for opening html tag. No closing `>` on the last `link` tag before `title`

Comment: Also, you are making an indefinite recursive call for ```showTime()``` It will keep create ```setTimeout``` in the background.

Answer (score 1):

First, you should use `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout`.

Second, you should use `` ` `` instead of `'` to output the time.

```js
const time = document.getElementById('time'),
  greeting = document.getElementById('greeting'),
  name = document.getElementById('name'),
  focus = document.getElementById('focus');

function showTime() {
  let today = new Date(),
    hour = today.getHours(),
    min = today.getMinutes(),
    sec = today.getSeconds();
  //Set Am or PM
  const amPM = hour >= 12 ? 'PM' : 'AM';

  //12hr Format 
  hour = hour % 12 || 12;

  //Output Time
  time.innerHTML = `${hour}<span>:</span>${min}<span>:</span>${sec}${amPM}`;
}

setInterval(showTime,1000);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"> 
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial- 
     scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2? 
     family=Quicksand&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" >
     <title>Welcome Page</title>
</head>

<body>
  <time id="time">12:34:56 PM</time>
  <h1>
    <span id="greeting">Good Afternoon</span>
    <span id="name" contenteditable="true">Heather</span>
  </h1>

  <h2>What Is Your Focus For Today?</h2>
  <h2 id="focus" contenteditable="true">FIX THIS ISH ! </h2>
  <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

problems:-

> instead of backtik(``) you have used single quote('')
>
> Run (previous line of calling showTime)

try this code.....

```
const time = document.getElementById('time'),
  greeting = document.getElementById('greeting'),
  name = document.getElementById('name'),
  focus = document.getElementById('focus');

function showTime() {
  let today = new Date(),
    hour = today.getHours(),
    min = today.getMinutes(),
    sec = today.getSeconds();
  //Set Am or PM
  const amPM = hour >= 12 ? 'PM' : 'AM';

  //12hr Format 
  hour = hour % 12 || 12;

  //Output Time
  time.innerHTML = `${hour}<span>:</span>${min}<span>:</span>${sec}`;

  setTimeout(showTime, 1000);
}
showTime();
```

Comment: sorry for not removing 'Run'. hope it will work now

Comment: You can add the code in SO code snippet https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/356679/14032355

Comment: YES! Thank you SO MUCH ! Two days on the wrong tics !!!

Comment: Did you enclose the template literal by Backtik?

Comment: And hope you didn't forget to call setTimeout(showTime, 1000) inside the showTime function. Or you can use setInterval (showTime,100) instead of setTimeout call outside.

Answer (score 0):

it was the backticks in my JS THANKS !

```js
const time = document.getElementById('time'),
  greeting = document.getElementById('greeting'),
  name = document.getElementById('name'),
  focus = document.getElementById('focus');

function showTime() {
  let today = new Date(),
    hour = today.getHours(),
    min = today.getMinutes(),
    sec = today.getSeconds();
  //Set Am or PM
  const amPM = hour >= 12 ? 'PM' : 'AM';

  //12hr Format 
  hour = hour % 12 || 12;

  //Output Time
  time.innerHTML = '${hour}<span>:</span>${min}<span>:</span>${sec}';

  setTimeout(showTime, 1000);
}
Run
showTime();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" <head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial- 
     scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2? 
     family=Quicksand&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" <title>Welcome Page</title>
</head>

<body>
  <time id="time">12:34:56 PM</time>
  <h1>
    <span id="greeting">Good Afternoon</span>
    <span id="name" contenteditable="true">Heather</span>
  </h1>

  <h2>What Is Your Focus For Today?</h2>
  <h2 id="focus" contenteditable="true">FIX THIS ISH ! </h2>
  <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please share more details. The code you've shared intially does not contain any backticks, neither does the code from your answer